inheritance issue with derived class and multiple inheritance
I have following architecture
class A_Base {
    virtual foo() { } }

class A_Derived : public A_Base  {
    foo () { } }

class B_Base : A_Base {
    bar() { foo() } 
}

class B_Derived : public B_Base, A_Derived {
}

int main () {
    B_base var = B_Derived();

    var.bar(); // calls foo() from class A_Base and not A_Derived  
}

B_base has to heritate from A_base.
How can I make that when calling var.bar(), bar is called from A_Derived and not A_Base

Your code doesn't compile (due to multiple errors - missing ;s, missing return values etc.). Please post code that actually compiles if you need help with runtime issues.

Note that as posted foo in A_Base is private (by default) and so cannot be called from a derived class like B_Base.

You will have to make bar virtual and override it in B_derived. There is no way that B_Base can know about A_derived and its foo if it doesn't inherit it itself.

every time you forget a ; after a class definition a kitten dies somewhere. (and your code fails to compile)

all methods are private in your example. Please show the real code, that actually demonstrates what you want to demonstrate

your code has more typos than I can count. I tried to fix them, but when I reached main I stopped, because thats not just typos, but plain wrong

You might be thinking of dominance; if A_Base was a virtual base of B_Base and of A_Derived the code (once fixed, as many comments have noted) would call A_Derived::foo. But that's a different class hierarchy from the one shown, and such a change should be driven by design requirements. There are good reasons to use virtual bases and good reasons to use non-virtual bases, and there is nothing in the question that suggests which approach would be more appropriate.

Calling B_base::bar will always call A_Base::foo if you do so from an object of type B_Base. Take a look at the class hierarchy of B_Base:
B_Base -> A_Base

A derived class of B_Base could override foo, but that's not the case in this example.
All the other classes you defined in your question are completely unused (beside object slicing), so it's normal no fonctions from then are called. What you probably meant is to have such main:
int main() {
   B_Base* var = new B_Derived();

   var->bar();

   delete var;
}

Now your main function makes sense as you actually create instances of them.

Now an explanation of why it doesn't work: C++, by default, resolves classes and inheritance statically. It means that the vtables are assembled by the compilers. When compiling a class, it will create a vtable with what it sees:
class A_Base {
    virtual void foo() { }
};

class B_Base : A_Base {
    void bar() { foo() } 
};

Since the compiler lookup the hierarchy and sees nothing else than A_Base, it will write A_Base::foo in its vtable.
But you will say that B_Derived had to have a vtable too with the overridden function in it! Well, no. B_Derived does not override anything either. A_Derived does, but A_Derived does not inherit from B_Derived.
To make this whole example work, you'll need to properly add the missing ; from your class declarations, add the return type of functions, override the function in the most derived class, and also use virtual inheritance, which make it so you only have one A_Base instance:
class A_Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() { }
    virtual ~A_Base() { }
};

class A_Derived : public virtual A_Base {
    void foo () override { }
};

class B_Base : virtual A_Base {
    void bar() { foo() } 
};

class B_Derived : public B_Base, A_Derived {
    void foo() override {
        A_Derived::foo();
    }
}


Overriding in the most derived class "solves" the problem without virtual inheritance. And virtual inheritance "solves" the problem without overriding in the most derived class through dominance. (Huh,, just tried to look up an explanation of dominance, and every source I saw equates it with name hiding, which is nonsense; the rule is that since A_Derived::foo overrides A_Base::foo, it overrides it when A_Base::foo is called from B_Base as well)
